# Java の OutputStream の引数について。（(byte[])の際と(byte[],int,int)の際の違いについて）

Tags: java, 画像

png画像をDBにBLOB型で格納してあるものを、pngに再度成型してダウンロードを行う処理を書いていました。

```
    response.setContentType(filetype);
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition"
                    , "attachment; filename=\"" + encodedFileName + "\"");

            OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

            byte[] downloadData = tomuch.getFile();
            out.write(downloadData);
            out.write(downloadData,0,downloadData.length);

            out.close();
```

以上のようなコードを書いていたのですが、`out.write(downloadData)`の形ですとpngとしてダウンロードはできるものの読み込めない状態になってしまいました。
そこで下のように `out.write(downloadData,0,downloadData.length);` という形にしたところ正常にダウンロードでき、画像も元の通りに復元されていました。

２つの違いは引数として開始位置と終了位置を指定しているだけだと思うのですが、なぜ結果に差異が出るのかが調べてみてもよくわかりませんでした、なぜそのような結果になったのかご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: responseはなんというライブラリのなんというクラスのインスタンスですか？サービスを構築するのに何かフレームワークを使っているのであればその情報を追加すると良いと思います。通常はその2つの書き方に差はないと思いますが、実装に依る部分がないとは言えません。

Comment: @MNEMO さんコメントありがとうございます
追記方法がよくわからなかったのでコメントで追記します
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseのHttpServletResponse
だと思います（見当違いの事を言ってるかもしれません）

Comment: Servletなのですね。Servlet Containerは何を使っていますか、という話はあるのですが、そもそもServlet Containerによって実装が違うというのもあまりなさそうですよね。通常OutputStream派生クラスのwrite(b[])はwrite(b,0,b.length)で実装されたものがそのまま継承されると思うので…関係するとしたらflush()呼ばないと途中で切れる可能性があるとかですかね…。（この辺は当てずっぽうなので信じないでください。）

Comment: 壊れているファイルと壊れていないファイルをバイナリ比較してみてはいかがでしょう。大きさは同じですか？中身が全く違うのか途中までは同じなのかとかはどうでしょう。いろいろ調べてみると良いですよ。

Comment: @MNEMO ソフト入れてやってみます。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 2):

[Java API 仕様書の記述](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(byte%5B%5D))

> `write(b)`の汎用規約では、`write(b, 0, b.length)`を呼び出したときと同じ動作を行います。

にある通り、その2つの挙動は同じです。
例えば Tomcat の `ServletOutputStream` 実装である [`CoyoteOutputStream`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/e20760b5a15066c006da2144b30ab61cc80581d3/java/org/apache/catalina/connector/CoyoteOutputStream.java#L88-L91) では次のようになっています。

```java
    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        write(b, 0, b.length);
    }
```

したがって、

> なぜ結果に差異が出るのかが調べてみてもよくわかりませんでした、なぜそのような結果になったのかご教授お願いいたします。

もし仮に結果に差異が発生しているのであれば、質問文中にあるような書き換えが原因であるというのは勘違いで、他に要因があると考えられます。
(それが何なのかは現時点の質問文からはわからないので、特定するためには再現できるコードが必要です)